# bluestacks as emulator in Visual Studio/Mono

Tags: visual-studio-2010, android-emulator, bluestacks

How to use Bluestacks as an emulator when developing an app using Visual Studio or Mono

Comment: Solved...just start bluestacks and run the command "adb devices"...u will find a device like 5522: or some other number , this represents your bluestacks emulator, you can choose this emulator while debugging in visual studio.

Comment: Can you please explain it in detail....
Where do I need to run the adb command and how to attach to the process from visual studio

Comment: I am getting "List of devices attached" and empty list. On Visual studio for Mac. Bluestacks is already running.